# Using \newcommand works fine in LaTeX, but when I use htlatex the line of text that \newcommand was supposed to insert gets moved to the next line?

Tags: macros, tex4ht, html, htlatex

So, I'm trying to write lines of code explaining to new students where to find different files and directories. Because the classname changes on a yearly basis I set up a `\newcommand` to make changing every class-name in the document at the same time possible. This is what my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{paper}

\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref, xcolor, graphicx}

\lstnewenvironment{lst}                             %Code-environment
{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{magenta},escapechar={§}}}{}

\newcommand{\class}{g2014048}                       %Classname

\begin{document}

\begin{lst}
$ cd /proj/§\class§
\end{lst}

\end{document}
```

When rendered into a `.pdf` it looks good, everything on one line:

> $ cd /proj/g2014048

But when I later use the `htlatex`-command in terminal to create a `.html` every "`\class`" gets a linebreak ahead if it:

> $ cd /proj/
>
> g2014048

Because it is a single line of code, I would like it to be that in the `.html` as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in `tex4ht` support for listings. When you look at generated code, you can see:

```html
 <!--l. 13--><pre class="listings"><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">$</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">cd</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">/</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">proj</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">/</span></pre><!--l. 14--><pre class="listings"><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">g2014048</span></pre><!--l. 14--><pre class="listings">
   <span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-3r2"></a></span></pre>
```

from this code it is obvious that escape to LaTeX caused end tag insertion and starting of new `<pre>` element. Same situation happened after escaped code, so now three `<pre>` elements instead of one were used, and visual result is broken line.

From inspection of `listings` source code and `tex4ht` configuration for it, it seems that macros redefined by `tex4ht` for insertion of tags is used not only at start and end of listings environment, but also sometimes inside the environment, like in the case of escaped LaTeX code.

I modified `tex4ht` configuration file for listings, `listings.4ht`, so the tags should be inserted only at the real beginning and end of listings environment. This needs some testing with real world samples and then we should report this at `tex4ht` bug database:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% listings.4ht                          2014-06-16-21:04 %
% Copyright (C) 2001--2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
%               2009--2014       TeX Users Group         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is the TeX4ht Project <tex4ht@tug.org>.                %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                                        tex4ht@tug.org  %
%                             http://www.tug.org/tex4ht  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2014-06-16-21:04}
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.

\newif\iflstnest
\append:defII\lst@EnterMode{%
  \iflstnest\typeout{lstnest true}\else\typeout{lstnest false}
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\:UnDef
     \let\lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
  \fi
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
      \pend:def\lsthk@EveryLine{\c:listings
             \def\dd:listings{\d:listings\let\dd:listings\empty}}%
  \fi
  \append:def\lsthk@EveryPar{\dd:listings}%
    \edef\:xtemp{Listing mode:\the\lst@mode}
    \expandafter\typeout\expandafter{\:xtemp}%
  \a:listings\fi\bgroup
  \Configure{$}{}{}{}%
  \aftergroup\lst:EnterMode}
\def\lst:EnterMode{\iflstnest\else\b:listings\fi\egroup\typeout{linsings end}}
\NewConfigure{listings}{4}
\let\dd:listings=\empty
\append:defI\lst@Init{\csname a:listings-init\endcsname\typeout{listings init}\global\lstnesttrue}
\pend:def\lst@DeInit{\csname b:listings-init\endcsname\typeout{listings init end}\global\lstnestfalse}
\NewConfigure{listings-init}{2}
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{%
   \Configure{listings}{}{}{}{}%
   \a:lstinline \bgroup \aftergroup\b:lstinline\aftergroup\egroup
  }
\NewConfigure{lstinline}{2}
\pend:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\lst:addcontentsline\addcontentsline
  \def\addcontentsline{\gHAdvance\TitleCount by 1
                       \lst:addcontentsline}%
}
\append:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\addcontentsline\lst:addcontentsline
}
\def\lst@NewLine{%
   \ifx\lst@OutputBox\@gobble\else \the\everypar \fi
   \global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne
   \lst@newlinetrue
}%
\def\lst@InputListing#1{%
    \begingroup
      \lsthk@PreSet \gdef\lst@intname{#1}%
      \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\lst@set}%
      \lsthk@DisplayStyle
      \catcode\active=\active
      \a:lstinputlisting \lst@Init\relax \let\lst@gobble\z@
      \lst@SkipToFirst
      \lst@ifprint \def\lst@next{\input{#1}}%
             \else \let\lst@next\@empty \fi
      \lst@next \lst@DeInit
      \b:lstinputlisting
    \endgroup}
\NewConfigure{lstinputlisting}{2}
\def\lst@Kern#1{%
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\kern#1}}}%
   \global\advance\lst@currlwidth \wd\z@
   \tmp:dim=#1 \let\:tempc=\empty
   \loop \ifdim \tmp:dim>\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\b:lst@Kern
      \append:def\:tempc{\:nbsp}%
   \repeat
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\:tempc}}}%
   \lst@OutputBox\z@}
\NewConfigure{lst@Kern}{2}
\Configure{lst@Kern}{0.499em}{0.1em}
\def\lst@outputspace{\:nbsp}

\HLet\lst@frameInit=\empty
\HLet\lst@frameExit=\empty

\Hinput{listings}
\endinput
```

Your example now looks fine:

```html
  <!--l. 13--><pre class="listings"><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">$</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">cd</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">/</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">proj</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">/</span><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">g2014048</span>
   <a 
 id="x1-3r2"></a></pre>
```

Comment: Wow great! I can't say I really understood what your solution actually did, but it worked so I'm happy :) Thanks!